# Error while starting rails server Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when im trying to start my server

```
rails s
```

Gives me the following error

> Administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in
>   `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while
>   trying to load the gem 'sidekiq'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

```
gem list
```

> sidekiq (4.0.1)

If you know how to resolve this problem, Please help.

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rails s` ? You are running from admin account , can you try with non admin account  too?

Comment: This is just username.It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update to:

```
- sidekiq 4.0.2
- celluloid 0.17.3
- sidetiq 0.6.3
```